# Thingsboard: The problem of create a widget library with attribute like widget control "led - indicator"

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, thingsboard

I am trying out a project about esp8266 sending data to "thingsboard" with Arduino IDE. Over time, I have also learned how to communicate between them. Like turning light bulbs on and off with "switch control" included in the widget libary sent with "RPC".

I plan to try creating a custom widget control that is not in the thingsboard library and if I create a widget. "thingsboard" requires HTML,CSS,JS. I also coded the HTML and CSS for a device that only works on and off. Do the same as the "Led-indicator" and I use "widget settings" to get the original "led-indicator"(tb-led-indicator-widget-settings). The most difficult thing now is how to do the JS part when I use Arduino IDE with the command tb.sendAtributeData("method" ,method_status); Widget control must know when the data sent is "false" or "true". The widget I created has the same widget settings as Led in "thingsboard", so it requires sending by "attribute" or "RPC".

This is my first time using "stackoverflow" to ask.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.